# Java: transparently handle state change event

Tags: java, oop

I have a view that has several "flag" buttons (`JToggleButton`).  When the user clicks a flag button, I want to update an array that keeps track of which buttons are flagged.  This is pretty simple, and here is what I have done:

```
...
   bflag[i].addItemListener(this); //View listens to state change
...

void itemStateChange(ItemEvent ie) {
   try {
      jtb = (JToggleButton)ie.getSource();
      //Update mark array
   }
   catch (ClassCastException cce) {}
}
```

This works just fine, but it is ugly with the try/catch.  I would much prefer to do something like this:

```
void itemStateChange(ItemEvent ie) {
   handleStateChange(ie.getSource());
}

void handleStateChange(JToggleButton jtb) {
   //handle state change
}

void handleStateChange(Object o) {}
```

This is much nicer, but the only problem is that the `Object` method will fire even if the source is a `JToggleButton` (because a `JToggleButton` is an `Object` after all).

I have also considered using double dispatch, but this would require overriding the `JToggleButton` method that fires `itemStateChange()`, and I don't know what that is (and that seems unsafe).

Any suggestions on how to get this to work without a try/catch, conditional check, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check for the Type explicitly I think.

```
  if(ie.getSource() instanceof JToggleButton){
      //toggle button logic
  }else{
      //something else
  }
```

Alternatively you can use anonymous inner classes to implement your listeners and avoid having to check the source altogether.

---

Something like this:

```
 toggleBtn.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
         public void itemStateChange(ItemEvent ie){
            //handle toggle button event
         }
 });
```

Comment: I think that is far uglier than the cast check (or at least equally ugly).  Please elaborate on the "anonymous inner class" scheme.

Comment: @tandu Even though the instanceof operator does not improve the beauty of the code it may be preferable to using an exception as a flow control mechanism. I also updated the answer with an example of using anonymous inner class.

Comment: The anonymous inner class would need to know about the view to get the array updated.  It doesn't.

Comment: The inner class can access any member of the containing class. So if the array is accessible from the containing class it should be accessible from the inner class.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  But the only problem is the array needs to be updated relative to the toggle button (there are multiple toggle buttons) and the anonymous class can't tell which button triggered the event either!

Comment: Using the ItemEvent's getSource you can get the actual button that triggered the event in the inner class. But, the difference is in this case you know whether it is a toggle button or not so you do not have to do the conditional check that you are trying to avoid.

Comment: getSource() still returns an `Object`

Comment: @tandu Yes. But since you are applying the itemlistener directly to a togglebutton and to that togglebutton alone you know that the type is a togglebutton and you can do away with the try catch altogether. So casting the Object to a JToggleButton is safe in this scenario.